# Parallelize Pandas's .size()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, multiprocessing, dill

I have the following code snippet using Python 3.10 and Pandas within a class method (not `__init__` since I noticed this could lead to problems):

```py
self.features = self.features.groupby(["token", "feature"], as_index=False).size() \
            .rename(columns={"size": "freq"})
```

My `self.features` DataFrame is very large, since I am processing a lot of textual data/documents. It also consists of elements from custom classes, which are not easily pickleable (I try to use dill whenever I can, e.g. for other parallelized tasks, I used pathos instead of standard multiprocessing).

Are there any ways of parallelizing the processing of `.groupby(...).size()`? I know there a few parallelization methods for Pandas, but they often use `.apply()` which I know is very slow.

Comment: at least post `self.features.head(10)`, and what's your current timing of executing `.groupby(...).size()` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`groupby.size` can be replaced by [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) that is quite faster.

```
features[['token', 'feature']].value_counts(sort=False).reset_index(name='freq')
```

Parallelizing won't be of much help as the limiting step (building the groups) cannot be parallelized.

Comment: That's interesting! Are there any comparisons on how much faster this method is compared to `groupby.size`? Or is there even any difference in complexity?

Comment: @TiMauzi it depends on several parameters (pandas version, number of groups, number of rows per group). Best is to try with your data ;)

Comment: Are there any variants I can try if my DataFrame is very large? Or is there at least an option to display a progress bar (like `tqdm`) so I can estimate the duration this operation will run?

Comment: I don't think so, a progress bar will only makes things slower. You can try [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts=True`, but I don't know if this will be faster when including the conversion.